# NiFi: Grabbing Multiple Regex Matches (Into an Attribute Using ExtractText?)

Tags: apache-nifi

Sample of what I'm processing:

```
<doc_filename>file1.docx</doc_filename>
...other data...
<doc_filename>file2.ppx</doc_filename>
...other data...
...more doc_filenames...
```

I need to extract what is between `<doc_filename></doc_filename>`.
My current attempt is using an ExtractText, with a regex string:

```
[<][d][o][c][_][f][i][l][e][n][a][m][e][>](.*<)[/][d][o][c][_][f][i][l][e][n][a][m][e][>].*
```

This works fine if there is only one `<doc_filename>`, but grabs far beyond the closing tag if not.  I have done a lot of googling and I can't seem to find a way to do this.  Am I missing something, or do I need to get a groovy script to do all of the processing here?

Note: I'm using these filenames later for further processing.

Thanks!

Comment: If there are limited number of doc_filename tags, you can use evaluatexpath processor. Groovy could be quite simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `ExtractText` processor, set **Include Capture Group 0** to `false`, **Enable repeating capture group** to `true`, and provide a dynamic property (click the '**+**' on the top right) with the property name **doc_filename** (or anything) and value `(?<=<doc_filename>)(.*?)(?=</doc_filename>)`.

The regex works as follows:

```
(?<=<doc_filename>) // Look-behind group to require opening tag
(.*?)               // Capture any characters, lazily
(?=</doc_filename>) // Look-ahead group to require closing tag
```

The resulting output (based on the example input you provided), will be:

```
2019-01-25 13:15:55,379 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5] o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=01681000-d047-1f22-14da-f93157703ba1] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=6908e84b-182d-4ffc-95e4-2efe5af00911,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1548450895799-1, container=default, section=1], offset=1233, length=137],offset=0,name=6908e84b-182d-4ffc-95e4-2efe5af00911,size=137]
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Fri Jan 25 13:15:55 PST 2019'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Fri Jan 25 13:15:55 PST 2019'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '137'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'doc_filename'
    Value: 'file1.docx'
Key: 'doc_filename.1'
    Value: 'file1.docx'
Key: 'doc_filename.2'
    Value: 'file2.ppx'
Key: 'filename'
    Value: '6908e84b-182d-4ffc-95e4-2efe5af00911'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: '6908e84b-182d-4ffc-95e4-2efe5af00911'
--------------------------------------------------
<doc_filename>file1.docx</doc_filename>
...other data...
<doc_filename>file2.ppx</doc_filename>
...other data...
...more doc_filenames...
```